# Filtering without submit button (Django)

Tags: python, html, django

I filter objects by choosing one in dropdown box and click submit button, then it will work.

But I don't want to click submit button. I need it work immediately after I click on alternative in dropdown box.

```
<form method="GET" class="form-inline">
    <select name="filtering" class="form-control">
        <option value="none">Alt 1</option>
        <option value="01">Alt 2</option>
        <option value="02">Alt 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter">
</form>
```

I have used HTML with Python/Django.

Answer (score 2):

Use `onchange="this.form.submit()"` in your select tag and remove submit button.

```
<select name="filtering" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```